# Tkinter Listbox will not return selected element

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

The code is as follows:

```
import tkinter as tk
plc=tk.Tk()
choices=["A","B","C]
choicesvar=tk.StringVar(value=choices)
l=tk.Listbox(master=plc,listvariable=choicesvar)
l.pack()
selected=l.get(l.curselection())
plc.mainloop()
```

The idea is to get what element is currently selected. But all I'm getting is TclError: bad listbox index "": must be active, anchor, end, @x,y, or a number.

Comment: You're asking to get the selection about a millisecond after creating the listbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`.curselections`](https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/listbox.html)
returns an empty tuple if nothing is selected. You are trying to get the user-selected input even before the user selects anything.

one way to overcome this is to set the default selection to the first row using `.selection_set(0)`

```py
...
l=tk.Listbox(master=plc,listvariable=choicesvar)
l.pack()
l.selection_set(0)
print(l.get(l.curselection()))
...
```

But since you want to get user selected row, bind the `<ButtonRelease>` to an event handler then get the selected rows. something as shown below.

```py
import tkinter as tk

def handler(event):
    print([l.get(index) for index in l.curselection()])
    

plc=tk.Tk()
choices=["A","B","C"]
choicesvar=tk.StringVar(value=choices)

l=tk.Listbox(master=plc,listvariable=choicesvar, selectmode=tk.MULTIPLE)
l.pack()
l.bind('<ButtonRelease>', handler)

plc.mainloop()
```

Comment: I did the second option, and I did it like this:

namesvar=tk.StringVar(names) #names is a list I loaded from a file
lis1=tk.Listbox(master=pop, listvariables=namesvar)
lis1.grid(row=0,column=0)

lis1.bind("<ButtonRelease>",handler1)

I defined handler1 as 
def handler1():
     print(lis1.get(list1.curselection()))

but I get error : TypeError: handler1() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given

Comment: It's better to bind on `<<ListboxSelect>>` than on `<ButtonRelease>`. The former will work whether the user uses the keyboard or the mouse to affect the selection, the latter will only work with the mouse.

Comment: @ivan199415 your function need to accept a paremeter check the above code the handler function has event as parameter. Also, as use `<<ListboxSelect>>` as Bryan suggested. (`handler1() ` should be `handler1(event)`)